# Hive - Error replacing with $ in regexp_replace

Tags: hadoop, hive

Running this line:
`regexp_replace('Hello from zzz','zzz','$15000')` gives an error saying:

Wrong arguments ''$15000'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace@6e85e0dd of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace with arguments {Hello from zzz:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, zzz:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, $15000:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 3

Is $ not supported? What is the alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **two back slashes (\\)** to escape $(is an regex special character)

```
 hive> select regexp_replace('Hello from zzz','zzz','\\$15000');
    +--------------------+--+
    |        _c0         |
    +--------------------+--+
    | Hello from $15000  |
    +--------------------+--+
```

There is **replace** function introduced in Hive-1.3.0+
Related [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13063) addressing replace function

If your replace string coming from a field in the **table** then use **concat function** to concatenate field value with **back slashes(\\)** and the other argument would be field name

```
   hive> select regexp_replace('Hello from zzz','zzz',concat('\\',"$15000"));
    +--------------------+--+
    |        _c0         |
    +--------------------+--+
    | Hello from $15000  |
    +--------------------+--+
```

**(or)**

```
hive> select regexp_replace('Hello from zzz','zzz',concat('\\',field/column-name))
```

Comment: Is it possible to escape the whole string? I am getting the replacement strings from another table with this one value causing the error.

Comment: Yep,
 **select regexp_replace('Hello from zzz','zzz',concat('\\',<field-name>));**